# Unknown column cms_page.path upgrading django-cms to 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm currently trying to upgrade an existing django-cms site from 3.0.16 to 3.1.4 with django 1.7.11

I followed the instructions given in http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.1.html but when I get to `python manage.py migrate`

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'cms_page.path' in 'field list'")
```

Any hints on how I can debug this? Thanks!

Update:

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 228, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 216, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 522, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 329, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 269, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 372, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/path/to/project/project/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 262, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), self.app_name, self.name
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 246, in get_urls
    url(r'^%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls))
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 598, in urls
    return self.get_urls()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/placeholderadmin.py", line 138, in get_urls
    from cms.urls import SLUG_REGEXP
File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    urlpatterns = get_app_patterns()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/appresolver.py", line 215, in get_app_patterns
    for title in title_qs.exclude(page__application_urls=None).exclude(page__application_urls='').order_by('-page__path').select_related():
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 701, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 787, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 129, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'cms_page.path' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Which application is migrating when you encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this worked, but the traceback indicated that there was some problem in my projects urls.py

I commented out all of the url rules in this file, migrated the cms app, then uncommented my url rules. That seems to solve the migration problem.